# Ubuntu Boot Repair

Tags: grubrescue, boot-repair

I have some questions about Boot Repair. Firstly, where/how can I get a CD of it? My friend and installed Ubuntu and I tried to remove it. Also, I may have deleted the GRUB files that get me out of it, so I was wondering how to use the Boot Repair while in GRUB rescue mode, if it's even possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download an ISO file from [Ubuntu's web site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), which you copy to a CD/DVD making a bootable OS and program. It will rewrite GRUB so you are able to boot from the hard disk.

Comment: Thanks! I have to use a separate computer right? (Sorry, I might sound dumb.) (Just making sure.)

Comment: You need to have an operational computer with internet connection, so I would say a second one would be needed.