# Error trying to boot into new grub entry

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I'm new to the whole Linux thing so I have very limited experience

So my problem is I have is Ubuntu with GNOME 16.04.1 LTS is not booting,   grub2 is on his my other installation of unity Ubuntu 16.04 and an extra Windows 10 all of these in separate drives as so

- HDD0 Windows 10
- HDD1 Ubuntu (unity)
- HDD2 Ubuntu with GNOME

Added the entry after installing by booting into unity and doing `sudo update-grub`

Booting into the new Ubuntu with gnome entry give me the error:

```
Error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd1' 
Error: you need to load the kernel first
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Your question/problem description is a little unclear. Can you please re-read it using the eyes of a bystander, and then edit to make it more precise? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you need to run boot-repair: http://askubuntu.com/questions/578213/ubuntu-boot-repair

Comment: When i try to run boot repair with in ubuntu in hdd1 and even a live ubuntu session its tries to run and does look like its trying to do some work but is interrupted by" -Filesystem repair requires to unmount partitions. Please close all your programs. Then close this window- " dispite there being no programs open