# How to boot Ubuntu from grub?

Tags: boot, grub2

I wanted to reinstall Ubuntu from the hard drive. I followed the instructions from the official site to install grub and move the Ubuntu iso in the grub folder.
After rebooting, the `grub>`  prompt shows up.

`ls` shows:

```
hd0, lvm/ubuntu--vg-root, lvm/ubuntu--vg-swap_1
```

but there is no `/dev/sda1` in `hd0` nor in `--vg-root`

How to fix this? What can be done to boot Ubuntu?

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/578213/ubuntu-boot-repair

Comment: @Melebius done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got into busybox by following first answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929833/how-do-i-boot-my-pc-from-grub/931327).

From busybox `blkid` gives info about location and name of root partition or drive. Writing this info in the commands found in an answer referred above booted into an OS.

I had to update grub and OS from 17.10 to 18.10 to fix this permanently.

Comment: Are you sure it’s 18.10? It’s not been officially released yet.